# How do I read multiple file lines and store them into different Objects Using Scanner

Tags: java, loops, csv, linked-list, java.util.scanner

I have a file that I am trying to read multiple lines from. But depending if it is a realtor line or a property line, it will store certain things into the line values array. I cant figure out the proper loop to read the lines properly Here is my code for reading the lines

```
    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String oneLine;
        String[] lineValues = null;
        oneLine = fileScanner.nextLine();

        lineValues = oneLine.split(",");

        if (lineValues[0].contains("REALTOR")) {
            if (lineValues[1].contains("ADD")) {                    
                processRealtorAddition(lineValues);                    
            } else if (lineValues[1].contains("DEL")) {
                realtorDeletion(lineValues);
            }
            else
                break;

        }  if (lineValues[0].contains("PROPERTY")) {
            System.out.println("fsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfsdfsdfds");                
            if (lineValues[1].contains("ADD")) {                    
                processPropertyAddition(lineValues);
                break;
            } else if (lineValues[1].contains("DEL")) {
                propertyDeletion(lineValues);
            }
        }             
    }
}
```

But when I run that I get this:

> The Realtor Object with a license number of MN4564567 has been added
>   fsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfsdfsdfds Realtor Log:
>
> Property Log: Property{mlsNumber=4455667, licenseNumber=MN4564567,
>   streetAdress=4455 This Circle, city=Denver, state=CO, zipCode=80333,
>   bedrooms=1, bathrooms=1.0, sold=false, askingPrice=344555.0} All
>   properties are correct BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

This is the file I'm trying to read:

> REALTOR,ADD,MN4564567,Carla,Combs,444-555-6666,0.014
>   PROPERTY,ADD,4455667,MN4564567,4455 This
>   Circle,Denver,CO,80333,1,1,N,344555
>   REALTOR,ADD,RR6655443,Jerry,Smith,555-444-3333,0.013
>   PROPERTY,ADD,23456789,RR6655443,888 Terry
>   Lane,Longmont,CO,80503,3,2,N,222222
>   REALTOR,ADD,AB1234567,Matthew,Munez,123-456-7890,0.012
>   PROPERTY,ADD,1234567,AB1234567,1234 Which
>   Way,Somewhere,CO,82222,3,3,Y,222222 PROPERTY,ADD,2234567,AB1234567,345
>   Main St,Fort Collins,CO,81333,4,3.5,N,222333 REALTOR,DEL,MN4564567
>   REALTOR,ADD,XY98765432,Alex,Yung,999-888-7777,0.013
>   PROPERTY,ADD,9998888,XY98765432,111 Main St,Cheyenne,WY,82222,1,1

,N,199888

I just need it to read the first line get all the right info, then start the while loop all over again then read the second line. Thanks!

This is the static method to process the addition

```
static void processPropertyAddition(String lineValues[]) {
    Property property = new Property(lineValues);

    boolean value1 = property.verifyMlsNumber();
    boolean value2 = property.verifyState();
    boolean value3 = property.verifyZipCode();

    if (value1 == false) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: invalid MLS number: "
                + property.mlsNumber + "\n");
    } else if (value2 == false) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid State: "
                + property.state + "\n");
    } else if (value3 == false) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid zip code: "
                + property.zipCode + "\n");
    }

    boolean value4 = realtorLogImpl.isLicenseUnique(property.getLicenseNumber());

    boolean value5 = propertyLogImpl.isMlsUnique(property.getMlsNumber());
    if (value4 == false && value5 == false) {
        propertyList.add(property);
    } else if (value5 == true && value4 == true) {
        propertyList.add(property);
    } else if (value4 == false && value5 == true) {
        propertyList.add(property);

        System.out.println("The Property with Realtor license number "
                + property.getLicenseNumber() + " and with MLS number"
                + property.getMlsNumber() + " has been added");
    } else if (value4 == true && value5 == false) {
        System.err.println(" Property will not be added due to "
                + "a Realtor license or a MLS number that is not "
                + "unique");
    }
}
```

This is the method of the `PropertyLogImpl` to add a property to the property linked list

```
  public boolean add(Property property) {
    return propertyList.add(property);
}
```

I have to have a method to add a property, I feel that this method may be incorrect and may be the cause of it

Comment: Do you know what the `break` statement does?

Comment: I forgot to remove the sysout fsdfdsfsdfdsfdsfsdfsd

Comment: Yes i do, this is what happens if I take out the break statements

Comment: The Realtor Object with a license number of MN4564567 has been added
fsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfsdfsdfds
The Realtor Object with a license number of RR6655443 has been added
fsdfsdfsdfdsfdsfsdfsdfds
ERROR: invalid MLS number: 23456789


IT just displays this and then it stays in an infinite loop

Comment: Well, we can't see the code that displays "invalid MLS number".  And the code that is staying in an infinite loop is probably also code you haven't shown us.  We don't have enough information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
 }  if (lineValues[0].contains("PROPERTY")) {
```

you probably wanted to write

```
 } else if (lineValues[0].contains("PROPERTY")) {
```

Also whenever you use `contains` you probaly wanted to use `equals` instead.

And as already mentioned in comments your usage of `break` statements is suspicious.

If you run into an infinite loop, there is nothing in the code shown so far that would cause this. It is possible the infinite loop comes from here:

```
realtorLogImpl.isLicenseUnique(property.getLicenseNumber());
```

It should be really easy to find the cause with a debugger (hint, hint, ...)

Comment: Ok im going to edit it and show you what happens after that

Answer (score 0):

`break` statement breaks out of the `for/while` loop.

If you remove the break statement after the `processPropertyAddition` method call, that should fix your bug.